# Show options - select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have two select lists. How, using jquery, can I show only the options in 2nd select with the same value of an option in 1st select?

E.g - for **clothes** in 1st select, show only `clothes - mens` and `clothes - ladies` from the 2nd list.

```
<select name="cat">
    <option value="1">clothes</option>
    <option value="2">shoes</option>
    <option value="3">other</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<select name="prod">
    <option value="1">clothes - mens</option>
    <option value="1">clothes - ladies</option>
    <option value="2">shoes - mens</option>
    <option value="2">shoes - ladies</option>
    <option value="3">other - mens</option>
    <option value="3">other - ladies</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained it could work for you

Comment: You should use two selects, and conditionally show the correct one.

Comment: This is pretty ugly, but works http://jsfiddle.net/bcXLJ/ but it would really be better to listen the comment above...

Comment: You should have one select as a selector and multiple select boxes as actors.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/YVtwY/

```
var prod = $('select[name=prod]');

$('select[name=cat]').on('change', function() {
    var self = $(this);

    // hide everything at first
    prod.find('option').hide();

    // show the selected
    prod.find('option[value='+ self.val() +']').show();

    // set the first item to be the first of the seleted
    prod.find('option[value='+ self.val() +']:first').prop('selected',true);
}).change();
```

Comment: Thx. Work in firefox, but not work in chrome. How fixed in chrome? Example last select http://1.ligapariurilor.ro/formular-anunturi

Comment: @mIH1 the fiddle has been tested on chrome and works. What issue are you seeing with the fiddle on chrome?

Comment: In this moment i have next code: http://jsfiddle.net/wP5xS/ ... Demo for last select in form 1.ligapariurilor.ro/formular-anunturi ... in firefox work corectly and in chrome not show option for 2nd select, all is set display:none.

Comment: @mIH1 Your fiddle works as it is coded, you have PHP in your fiddle which DOES NOT work in fiddle. The only value you have in the select is the first one with value=0 and that's why the other select is hidden, because in your code it defines if the select is 0 then hide the other dropdown

Comment: No works in fiddle, but i show you my site http://1.ligapariurilor.ro/formular-anunturi where you can see that does not display in chrome 2nd option, and in firefox is work.

Comment: @mIH1 your site has lines like localitate.find("option[name='" + self + "']") and var self = jQuery(this).attr("name"); where the options you have DOES NOT have any name attribute. The name you are setting to self is also the name of the select (judet). Of course it will not work. The way your handler is set up is different than the question asked. I have answered your question, if you have a different question then you should post another one. For some reason your second select does not have the corresponding values as the first select

Comment: I not have localitate.find("option[name='" + self + "']") and var self = jQuery(this).attr("name");. Please refresh page.

Comment: Your code don't work because in #localitate select, the option values all equal 1, except for the first one which is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this will work....

```
<script>
function find(value)
{
   if(value=="1")
   {
      $("select[name=prod]").html("<option>clothes-men</option><option>clothes-women</option>");
  }
}
</script>

<select name="cat" onchange="find(this.value)">
<option value="1">clothes</option>
<option value="2">shoes</option>
<option value="3">other</option>
</select>


<select name="prod">
</select>
```

Similarly write the code for the other two values "2" and "3". This code dynamically generates the values of the second drop down on the basis of the values from the first drop down list.